# Evaluate boolean tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm trying to get this to evaluate to false.

```
(False,)
```

It's currently equaled to true, because I think the tuple is not empty.
So how might one extract or cast this to a boolean?
Thanks~

Comment: how should the answer behave if there are more than one value in the tuple?

Comment: like this (False,)[0] ?

Comment: @Thibaut that would not be possible. It's returned from a boolean sql query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extract the element from the tuple is the most simple approach:

```
value = (False,)[0]
```

Python2 is more lenient, but in general it isn't good practice to treat a tuple as a single value for comparison purposes (Python3 explicetly bans it)

Instead, look at the

```
all
```

and

```
any
```

functions for this behavior. As always, the documentation is your friend:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

Comment: Thanks, second time python-ing. Didn't think that would work haha. It gave me a weird error when I tried using a for loop. I'll mark your answer as soon as it lets me.....

Comment: Edit: oh, you mean that you can't compare a tuple to an int or float any more using `<` or `>` etc.  I suppose that's true enough.

Comment: @DSM That is what I mean - it's just meant as an example of how to compare lists to non-lists, and why it probably isn't a good idea to to say "mylist == True" or similar, even if it would work in some cases. The error one can get "the truth value of an array is ambiguous" or something similar is pretty helpful, I think