# Why I am getting " Undefined Variable "?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python so hope to get some help with the issue. I am getting `Undefined Variable 'r'` error and I am kind of lost how to resolve it.

Tried defining 'r variable as int but did not work

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def Checkdiv(n, d):
    r =int(n % d)
    if r==0:
        return (True,r)
    else:
        return (False,r)
n= int(input('Please enter the number to evaluate:'))
d= int(input('Please enter the divisor: '))

if Checkdiv(n,d) is True :
    print(f'{n} can be divided by {d} since the end remainder is {r}')
else: 
    print (f'{n} cannot be divided by {d} since remainder is {r}')
```

Comment: Maybe share some code, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I am new to Stackflow -- looks like I need to learn this as well

Comment: Sounds like `r` is defined inside the function, but you try to access it from outside the function.

Comment: Put global r in your function

Comment: I would not advise using global as some have suggested. Although you return `r` inside your function `Checkdev`, you don't assign it to a variable outside the scope of the function. Instead call your function like this: `zero, r = Checkdiv(n, d)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define r outside the Checkdiv function and in the function use r variable as a global variable with global keyword; global r and then r=int(n % d). so that other code blocks will be able to see the r variable too.

```py
r = 0
def Checkdiv(n, d):
    global r
    r = int(n % d)
    if r==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
n= int(input('Please enter the number to evaluate:'))
d= int(input('Please enter the divisor: '))


if Checkdiv(n,d) is True :
    print(f'{n} can be divided by {d} since the end remainder is {r}')
else: 
    print (f'{n} cannot be divided by {d} since remainder is {r}')
```

Comment: I had to add " global r" the above syntax was giving me error but it worked - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: answer rendered useless after OP edit**

You try to call the function with paramaters n and d. You need to assign them before calling the function or directly input two numbers.
For example:

```py
n = 6
d = 2
if Checkdiv(n,d) is True:
   pass
```

Or

```py
if Checkdiv(6,2) is True:
   pass
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: He is taking input and using n and d

Comment: That is why there is an edit at the top of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just simply r is define only in your function, and in print you try to use r that is visable only localy in `Checkdiv`. You have to first write to variable result of `Checkdiv` and then use it in print function.

```py
def Checkdiv(n, d):
    r =int(n % d)
    if r==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    n= int(input('Please enter the number to evaluate:'))
    d= int(input('Please enter the divisor: '))
n = 6
d = 2
r = Checkdiv(n,d)
if r:
   print(f'{n} can be divided by {d} since the end remainder is {r}')
else:
   print (f'{n} cannot be divided by {d} since remainder is {r}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable ‘r’ only exists in the Checkdiv function, yet you refer to it outside the function:

```
print(f'{n} can be divided by {d} since the end remainder is {r}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to write your code would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def Checkdiv(n, d):
    r =int(n % d)
    if r==0:
        return (True,r)
    else:
        return (False,r)
n= int(input('Please enter the number to evaluate:'))
d= int(input('Please enter the divisor: '))

bool, num = Checkdiv(n,d)

if bool is True :
    print(f'{n} can be divided by {d} since the end remainder is {num}')
else: 
    print (f'{n} cannot be divided by {d} since remainder is {num}')
```

Comment: Interesting way of writing  - I learned something new here. In my example simple adding "global r" worked as well

Comment: Yes, I saw that in other answers. However, this way has the advantage that avoids the following question: which of the two values returned by the function is evaluated in the if? Is it always the first one? Is it a boolean one if it exists? What will happen if the first value is zero and the second something else (thus evaluating to True)?

Comment: @InderPahwa You can see the following question about why evaluating the function is bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964038/evaluate-boolean-tuple-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicate the problem.
Here is a simple code which does what you want to do :

```py
def check_div(n,d):
    r = n % d
    if r == 0:
        print('{} can be divided by {} since the end remainder is {}'.format(n ,d, r))
    else:
        print('{} cannot be divided by {} since remainder is {}'.format(n, d, r))

n= int(input('Please enter the number to evaluate:'))
d= int(input('Please enter the divisor: '))

check_div(n, d)
```

The problem with your code that you should define r outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have trouble with the lifetime of value, variable declared inside a function (except if used with global keyword) stop to be referenced when the function return and so are deleted by the garbage collector.

But in your code you return r, so why it don't work? 
Well you return a tuple (boolean, int).

when you are doing

```
if Checkdiv(n,d):
```

you evaluate if the tuple is empty not if the boolean values.
and after the return value are lost because they are not assigned.

you can decompose your code to have those value ( you can check python unpack)

```
boolean, r = Checkdiv(n,d)
# now you can test and use the return value,
```